# Python Binary Divide by 2 method

Tags: python, binary

I'm looking for the out put of this, which is how i get Binary code using the divide 2 method

```
number= int(input(22))
22 / 2 = 11 R 0
11 / 2 = 5 R 1
5 / 2 = 2 R 1
2 / 2 = 1 R 0
1 / 2 = 0 R 1
answer = 10110
print(answer)
```

With the code I currently have, I'm getting the output `11110`.
The remainder is what I need to put into a list or a string, and I'm guessing I need to use a While loop, or a for loop.

Here is my code:

```
binar=""
number=0
while number<=0:
    try:
        number=int(input("Enter a number"))
    except:
        print("That is not a number!")
        continue
print(number)
if (number % 2) == 0:
    num=0
    binar = str(num) + binar
else:
    num=1
    binar = str(num) + binar
while int(number) > 1:
    number=int(number)/2
    print(number)
    if (number % 2) == 0:
        num=0
        binar = str(num) + binar
    else:
        num=1
        binar = str(num) + binar
print(binar)
```

It's really sloppy. I do have the begging making sure the input is a actual number, and not string. The number can not be 0, or a negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursion function for that :

```
def binary(a,l=[]):
 if a>0:    
    l.append(a%2)
    return binary(a/2)
 else:
    return ''.join(map(str,l[::-1]))

print binary(22)
```

result :

```
10110
```

In this function while `a>0` we append `a%2` to a list and call function with `a/2` at last we would have a list that we need to reverse (`l[::-1]`) and convert to string (`map(str,l[::-1])`) and at last concatenated (`''.join()`) !

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is too complicated.

You showed that you want to calculate the result and the remainder of a division of a number by 2, then save the remainder, set the result as new number and do it again until the result ist zero.

For that purpose there is a divmod function in python:

```
result, remainder = divmod(dividend, divisor)
```

You can use it after you got the number:

```
remainders = []
while number:
    number, remainder = divmod(number, 2)
    remainders.append(remainder)
print "".join([str(r) for r in remainders[::-1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Import math and use the code `math.ceil` after you divide the number by two. It will look something like this

```
if (number % 2) == 0:
    num=0
    binar = str(num) + binar
else:
    num=1
    binar = str(num) + binar
while int(number) > 1:
    number=int(number)/2
    number=math.ceil(int(number))
    print(number)
    if (number % 2) == 0:
        num=0
        binar = str(num) + binar
    else:
        num=1
        binar = str(num) + binar
```

That will solve the problem. And to print in revers just do `print(name[::-1])`